# Parse data from JSON response

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a JSON response data as follows

```
{"response":"9",
 "status":"Success",
 "msg":"Valid Access",
 "data":[{"id":"1","title":"A"},
        {"id":"2","title":"B"},
        {"id":"3","title":"C"}]
 }
```

How can I fetch only the data array using jquery?

Showing error as `parsererror; SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected non-whitespace character after JSON data at line 1 column 666 of the JSON data` in console while parse/stringify

Comment: `data.data` like this

Comment: `obj = { ....};` then `obj.data = [{}, {}]`

Comment: using jquery?! use the correct tools people! - also, this is a duplicate

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Parse JSON in JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4935632/parse-json-in-javascript)

Comment: Use an online JSON validator. Your JSON string is invalid, which is why you're seeing that error.

Answer (score 4):

Use dot notation

```
var obj = {"response":"9",
 "status":"Success",
 "msg":"Valid Access",
 "data":[{"id":"1","title":"A"},
        {"id":"2","title":"B"},
        {"id":"3","title":"C"}]
 }

console.log(obj.data);
```

https://jsfiddle.net/c8z35au4/

or parse the data

```
var unparsed = '{"response":"9",
     "status":"Success",
     "msg":"Valid Access",
     "data":[{"id":"1","title":"A"},
            {"id":"2","title":"B"},
            {"id":"3","title":"C"}]
     }';
var obj = JSON.stringify(unparsed);
console.log(obj.data);
```

Comment: @Vinod That probably means you haven't parsed the JSON string and the string object doesn't have `data` property.

Answer (score 3):

If it's Ajax request:

```
$.ajax({
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function (response) {
        console.log(response.data);
    }
});
```

If it's string, than use `var response = JSON.parse(string)` and `response.data`

Comment: `parsererror; SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected non-whitespace character after JSON data at line 1 column 666 of the JSON data`

Comment: @Vinod This error means that your JSON response contains more than JSON. Like `{id: 5}(int)5`. Clean your JSON first than

Comment: I got response from `http://www.vtc.com/services/api/restApiClient/?task=getAllCategories`

Answer (score 2):

```js
var data = {"response":"9",
 "status":"Success",
 "msg":"Valid Access",
 "data":[{"id":"1","title":"A"},
        {"id":"2","title":"B"},
        {"id":"3","title":"C"}]
 }
 
 
 
 console.log(JSON.stringify(data.data))
```

Comment: AS simple as this :)

Answer (score -1):

The best way is

```
 var data = {"response":"9",
     "status":"Success",
     "msg":"Valid Access",
     "data":[{"id":"1","title":"A"},
            {"id":"2","title":"B"},
            {"id":"3","title":"C"}]
     }

    data=JSON.parse(data);
   var requiredData=data.data;
   for(var i in requiredData)
{
     var id = requiredData[i].id;
     var title = requiredData[i].title;
     console.log(id);
     console.log(title);

}
```